# Judge Universities Across

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about the usage of the preposition "***across***" [here](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2016/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/rank_label/sort_order/asc/cols/rank_only):

> The Times Higher Education World University Rankings 2015-2016 list the best global universities and are the only international university performance tables to judge world class universities ***across*** all of their core missions - teaching, research, knowledge transfer and international outlook.

I understand usages of "*across*" like these:

> dialogues ***across*** ethnic groups
>   cooperation ***across*** national borders

But, I don't quite get the pattern "*judge universities* ***across*** *some criteria*".  But "*judge universities* ***on*** *some criteria*" seems better.

Would replacing "*across*" with "*on*":

> ...the only international university performance tables to judge world class universities ***on*** all of their core missions...

be better?

Comment: This just looks like a peeve. There's nothing inherently incorrect about, for example, [80 entries from 16 countries were judged across ten categories](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22were+judged+across+ten%22), or [Winners were judged across a range of criteria.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22were+judged+across+a+range%22)

Comment: It is not "across some" but "across *all*".

Answer (score 1):

The underlying spatial meaning of *across* in "across all their core missions"  would be something like "extending to include". It is related to the idea of a "range".

**Product B was preferred across all age groups.**

The preference for B extends beyond a single age group to all age groups.

This is a [very common use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=across%20all&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cacross%20all%3B%2Cc0) of the word **across** in contexts where multiple categories or criteria are involved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

> on

in your example, however it might not be as descriptive, since

> across

also has the possible implication of interactions between the different "core missions" or criteria.  Merely using "on" may mean that each mission/criteria is placed in a silo when judged against competing universities, and these days one of the big initiatives is *cross disciplinary studies*.